# Bash: can't call a function; No such file or directory

Tags: bash, function

I am having huge issues that have blocked me all day.

I have a number of functions files with various functions based on use, ie. SSH, logging etc.

I have a script that runs where I add errors to an error array which is global. I have an error trap that calls a script in another 'exit_functions' file.

In this exit_functions file I do various things, but the part I am having issues with is a loop that runs of this array and pulls out the array elements which are actually commands. These commands are **functions** within one of the functions files that have been included in the calling script using the normal . /path/to/functions_file syntax.

All my other functions such as logging etc are working out of the exit_functions file, it is just these particular functions that can't be called. I get an error:

```
/functions/exit_functions: line 109: closeSSHTunnel /tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck: No such file or directory
```

Now, killSSHTunnel is a function that sits in a functions file that has been included previously just as other functions files have been included. I only get this error using these functions calls out of an array.

I am not sure if I have described it properly - please let me know if I can provide any other info.

---

**EDIT full function code below:**

**/functions/exit_functions file:**
    exitTrap (){
        local LCL_SCRIPT_ERROR

```
    if [ $ERR_COUNT_EXIT_FUNCT -gt 0 ]; then
        for LCL_SCRIPT_ERROR in "${ERROR_ARRAY[@]}"; do
            case $LCL_SCRIPT_ERROR in
                SVN_IMPORT      )   # match the SVN_IMPORT error name and search for specific commands to run
                                    exitMsg "$LCL_SCRIPT_ERROR; 111"
                                    executeErrorActions $LCL_SCRIPT_ERROR

                                    exitScript 111
                                    ;;

                *               )   exitMsg "$LCL_SCRIPT_ERROR; 255"
                                    exitScript 255
                                    ;;
            esac
        done
    fi
}
```

So my test code introduces an error state that ends up calling the function above (exitTrap). It has already populated an array named ERROR_ARRAY.

So the executeErrorActions function, also in /functions/exit_functions, loops over the associative array, ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY, looking for a key named (in this test) **SVN_IMPORT**. When it finds this key it is looking for a string that is ':' delimited. Each delimited section will be a separate command that I was to run when this error condition arises. In my test I have a **single** entry (no delimiters) that is simply: *closeSSHTunnel /tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck*

Now, with the function below it works fine when I **do not** include the section between IFS= and unset IFS and instead just use the single line that has the double comments hashes below. As soon as I introduce the IFS separator to break the string up I get the error:

> /functions/exit_functions: line 109: closeSSHTunnel /tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck: No such file or directory

```
executeErrorActions (){
    if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    local ERROR_NAME=$1
    local ERROR_ACTION

    #ERROR_KEY="SVN_IMPORT"

    for ERROR_ACTION in ${!ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[@]}; do
        #echo KEY: $i VALUE: ${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$i]}
        if [ $ERROR_NAME == $ERROR_ACTION ]; then

            ##$(${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]})

            IFS=":"
            for i in ${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]}; do
                $i
            done
            unset IFS
            return 0
        fi
    done
}
```

Here is the set -x output of the test run using two ':' delimitered commands, the same *closeSSHTunnel* function above and a simple *ls -la* call. I add these to the ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY using the addError function call as below:

```
addError SVN_IMPORT closeSSHTunnel $SSH_TUNNEL_LCK_FILE:ls -la
```

This is the set -x output:

```
+ executeErrorActions SVN_IMPORT
+ '[' '!' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ local ERROR_NAME=SVN_IMPORT
+ local ERROR_ACTION
+ for ERROR_ACTION in '${!ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[@]}'
+ '[' SVN_IMPORT == SVN_IMPORT ']'
+ IFS=:
+ for i in '${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]}'
+ 'closeSSHTunnel /tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck'
/functions/exit_functions: line 116: closeSSHTunnel /tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck: No such file or directory
+ for i in '${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]}'
+ 'ls -la'
/functions/exit_functions: line 116: ls -la: command not found
+ unset IFS
+ return 0
```

**Note how one of them says 'No such file or directory and the other says 'command not found'. This is now day 2 trying to sort this out !**

***My conclusion is that the IFS change and the string breakup is causing issues.***

**EDIT 2**

If I move the IFS calls around a bit and terminate the IFS on the ':' char inside the loop and then establish it again after the execute call it all works !!!!!!

```
for ERROR_ACTION in ${!ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[@]}; do
        #echo KEY: $i VALUE: ${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$i]}
        if [ $ERROR_NAME == $ERROR_ACTION ]; then
            #$(${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]})
            IFS=$':'
            for i in ${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]}; do
                unset IFS
                $i
                IFS=$':'
            done
            unset IFS
            return 0
        fi
done
```

Can anyone explain this ?

Comment: Does the file `/tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck` exist?

Comment: Can you post the code of `killSSHTunnel` and indicate which line is line 109?

Comment: @choroba - I posted code below as an answer so that I could get the code highlighting. I hate that I can't paste code in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have IFS set to ":" -- bash uses IFS to split the variable into words (i.e. the function name vs. its arguments), not into separate commands. Thus, it's trying to run a command named `closeSSHTunnel /tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck`, not a command named `closeSSHTunnel` with the argument `/tmp/ssh_tunnel_iA0yj.lck`.

```
$ ERROR_ACTION="echo something"
$ $ERROR_ACTION 
something
$ IFS=":"
$ $ERROR_ACTION 
-bash: echo something: command not found
$ ERROR_ACTION="echo:something"
$ $ERROR_ACTION 
something
```

If you want to be able to include multiple commands, you'll have to split them yourself.

EDIT: Given the more complete script excerpt, what you need is for IFS to be set to ":" when the `for` splits the command, but be back to normal when you execute the command:

```
...
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=":"
for i in ${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]}; do
    IFS="$saveIFS"
    $i
done
IFS="$saveIFS"
```

This resets IFS more than is strictly necessary, but it's easier to do that than add the logic to figure out when it actually needs to be reset (and BTW the final reset is there in case the loop never executes).

Comment: Yes - I was splitting exactly like that. So my commands are somethign like: "closeSSHTunnel user PID.lck" when I only have one command and no IFS call to split the string it all works fine. As soon as I include the IFS=":" and split the string (even if I only have one element in there with no delimiters) I get the file not found error. I am wondering if the string split is wrapping single quotes around the result or something.

Comment: I have posted a better description of the code and the issues in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know if this was the right way to do this but I looped over the string with IFS=":" and put that into an array and then reset the IFS. I then loop over that array of commands to execute them. All working.

```
executeErrorActions (){
    if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    local ERROR_NAME=$1
    local ERROR_ACTION
    local ACTION_ARRAY
    local ACTION

    if [ ${#ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
        for ERROR_ACTION in ${!ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[@]}; do
            if [ $ERROR_NAME == $ERROR_ACTION ]; then
                if [ ${#ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]} -gt 0 ]; then
                    IFS=$':'
                    ACTION_ARRAY=( ${ERROR_ACTION_ARRAY[$ERROR_ACTION]} )
                    unset IFS
                    for ACTION in ${!ACTION_ARRAY[@]}; do
                        exitMsg "Running action for $ERROR_ACTION"
                        ${ACTION_ARRAY[$ACTION]}
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                            exitMsg "Error action succeeded"
                        else
                            exitMsg "Error action failed"
                            return 1
                        fi
                    done
                    return 0
                else
                    return 1    #no contents in the array element; no actions to run; maybe there should have been; return error
                fi
            else
                return 0    #no matching actions for this error; still return success
            fi
        done
    else
        return 0    #action array is empty
    fi
}
```